# How to check the air intensity in iphone programatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am developing an iPhone app which uses microphone of the device to measure the intensity of air blown.

Can anyone please tell me how to find the intensity of air blown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this a while ago.  You should consider checking out Apple's official example code, aurioTouch. You're going to end up doing something with FFTs (Fast Fourier Transforms).

[Linky-doo-dad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope this helps.